# requiring a file within a method

Tags: ruby

I was looking at the contents of the Ransack ruby gem. Basically, it calls a method called `require_constants`. And that method itself requires a file:

```
# ransack.rb
require 'ransack/adapters'
Ransack::Adapters.object_mapper.require_constants

# adapters.rb
module Ransack
  module Adapters

    def self.object_mapper
      @object_mapper ||= instantiate_object_mapper
    end

    def self.instantiate_object_mapper
      if defined?(::ActiveRecord::Base)
        ActiveRecordAdapter.new
      elsif defined?(::Mongoid)
        MongoidAdapter.new
      end
    end

    class ActiveRecordAdapter
      def require_constants
        require 'ransack/adapters/active_record/ransack/constants'
      end
      ...

# constants.rb
module Ransack
  module Constants
```

The first `require` copies the content of adapters.rb in ransack.rb, I believe. Hence, we can then reference `Ransack::Adapters` without an undefined error.

However, when we call `require_constants`, it appears to copy the contents of `Ransack::Constants` into the method definition of `require_constants`.

I find that kind of confusing. We are copying a module inside of a method. What benefit do we get of copying a module inside of a method, rather than just doing it like the other `require`? Second, I know the module is not a local variable, but I couldn't even define a module in the console when I tried it:

```
class A
  def a
    module B end
  end
end
SyntaxError: (irb):14: module definition in method body
```

So what is `require` doing that does not cause the syntax error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Copy" is the wrong word here. `require` does not copy anything. It reads the source code in the given file and executes that code in Ruby's global ("`main`") context (unless the file has already been `require`d; then it does nothing and returns `false`). To quote [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-require) (emphasis mine):

> Any constants or globals within the loaded source file will be available *in the calling program’s global namespace*.

`require` does not behave differently inside a method call, or inside a module, or anywhere else, than it does at the top of a file.

When you see `require` inside a method call the reason is usually that the module is only needed in a particular scenario, and loading it before that scenario occurs would be wasteful (because, for example, the module takes a long time to load or accesses, during loading, resources that are only available in that scenario—think different database drivers or OSes). It does not mean that the module is being loaded "into" the method or the surrounding code, because that's not what `require` does.

To demonstrate, suppose we have a module like this:

```
# baby_module.rb
module BabyModule
  NAME = "Baby"
end
```

And suppose we run the following program:

```
module TheCorner
  def self.load_baby_module
    require File.expand_path("baby_module", __dir__)
  end
end

TheCorner.load_baby_module

if defined?(TheCorner::BabyModule)
  puts "#{TheCorner::BabyModule::NAME} is in TheCorner"
elsif defined?(BabyModule)
  puts "Nobody puts #{BabyModule::NAME} in TheCorner"
end
```

As you have perhaps already guessed, this program's output will be:

> Nobody puts Baby in TheCorner

Answer (score 1):

> So what is `require` doing that does not cause the syntax error?

Simple: it runs the file.